# Getting DNSException: Error trying to resolve?

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to publish a post to my Twitter account...for this i am making a call to url:

```
con=(HttpConnection)Connector.open("http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json");
```

I am able to publish to my Twitter account from the simulator but the problem occurs on device...I am getting Getting  "DNSException: Error trying to resolve.."...

I have read the posts regarding this...the say that the url may be wrong...but i am successful in publishing post from simulator...the problem is only on device...

I am using WAP 2.0 connection...and i am getting WAP2Trans as connection UID..

any help in this regard will be appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use WAP from the simulator, so on the simulator it would be using MDS or direct TCP depending on how you have configured and started the simulator.

Have a look at this [video tutorial](http://www.blackberry.com/DevMediaLibrary/view.do?name=NetworkingTransports) for information on how to establish a WAP connection.